# Automatically execute plugin in wordpress without activating them?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Whenever we use any plugin in wordpress , we need to go to plugin option and then we have to activate them to use them , its fine !

Now my question is

> what if someone wants to execute the plugin by default without activating them ?

It means just install that plugin and that plugin will automatically execute on our site without any activation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Mubeen for your answer but i just found another solution which is very simple and easy to understand !

Just create a folder name

> mu-plugins

folder directory should be

> /wp-content/mu-plugins

just download any plugin from www.wordpress.com and extract them and simply copied them in this folder , you will see a new tab in your wordpress plugins option as

> Must-Use

the plugins under this tab will automatically executed on your site but there is a problem that if you want to deactivate that plugin then you have to delete that plugin from mu-plugins folder.

source:
http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/02/02/creating-a-custom-functions-plugin-for-end-users

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for auto activation WordPress plugin, this will help you to solve your auto activation plugin problem.

```
<?php

// example on admin init, control about register_activation_hook() 
add_action( 'admin_init', 'your_activate_plugins_function' );

// the exmple function
function your_activate_plugins_function() {

    if ( ! current_user_can('activate_plugins') )
        wp_die(__('You do not have sufficient permissions to activate plugins for this site.'));

    $plugins = FALSE;
    $plugins = get_option('active_plugins'); // get active plugins

    if ( $plugins ){
        // plugins to active
        $pugins_to_active = array(
            'hello.php', // Hello Dolly
            'adminimize/adminimize.php', // Adminimize
            'akismet/akismet.php', // Akismet
            'find-any-think/create-plugin-index.php' // Find any think Plugin
        );

        foreach ( $pugins_to_active as $plugin ) {
            if ( ! in_array( $plugin, $plugins ) ) {
                array_push( $plugins, $plugin );
                update_option( 'active_plugins', $plugins );
            }
        }

    } // end if $plugins

}

?>
```

Thanks, I Hope your problem will be solve by this code.

Comment: Why you are want to auto active plugin after upload? that will make problem for you.

Comment: I have told you this will make problem, if you will auto execute any plugin after installation, so you have to remove it when you not in need of that. right now you are facing a little problem, in further you will have many problem if you auto execute any plugin right form installation, Thank You.